# How can I change the font color of a disabled SELECT element? (Works in Firefox but not in IE)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, disabled-control

How can I change the font color of a disabled SELECT element in IE? No matter what I tried it stays gray. I was able to change the background from gray to white but the text inside the disabled SELECT stays the same. What works perfectly for Firefox has no effect in terms of font color in IE (in this case IE8). You can see the latest situation for both browsers here:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/64416865@N00/4732813702/

I use jQuery to disable the select element:

```
$(selectObject).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and here is the CSS class that I use for disabled selects:

```
select[disabled] {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

I find it very strange that I could easily change the default background color of disabled selects but not the default font color. Any tips or ideas about this? (Or is this completely impossible in IE by using CSS?)

Comment: use jquery to change it too, see my answer

Comment: Does it work if you set the select to be disabled directly? You need to work out if your css or JavaScript is letting you down.

Comment: Richard, what do you mean by "set the select to be disabled directly"?

Comment: CuSS, I tried. Does not work (for text's color). See my comments to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It might be impossible to do in current IEs. Browsers to come will probably support a :disabled pseudo-class (see http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-24.html )

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-24.html the css Emre is using is supported by IE 7 and above.

Comment: It's important to note that IE7/8 will only work with attribute selectors if a DOCTYPE is defined correctly. So no quirks mode.

Comment: at least in my case, the problem is not the selector: I'm using a hand-assigned class on the disabled <select> and neither text-color, nor color on the <select> itself or the containing <options> has any effect. The text of the options is gray. period.

Comment: IE11 does support the `:disabled` pseudo-class, but `color` is simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: You have to supply support for the most browsers, and only 50% of the browsers supports that type of pseudoclasses, so, if i was you, i would do this:

```
$(selectObject)
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .css({
        "color":"black",
        "background-color":"white",
        "border-style":"solid"
    });
```

hope it works ;)

Comment: I did it. I have removed the relevant CSS and ran it like your jQuery code above. What is really strange is that, when I look at the page the select's background is still white and the text inside is still gray but I use the Internet Explorer developer tools to see the style details of that select element and when I click on it IE developer tool's CSS pane tells me that: color: black and background-color: white. I'm truly perplexed!

Comment: I played with different color names for "color" and "background-color", background color always changes, text's color always remains the same: gray. :(

Comment: strange, do you have another js line controling the font and background color?

Comment: CuSS, no, as far as I can see. Here's the complete code of the function that runs when the SELECT element is manipulated: http://pastebin.com/S5qqLcH7

Comment: As you see I also tried to swap the order of .attr and .css, nothing changes for both cases.

Comment: Please email me, to i clean this comment: jmoreira@microdual.com

Answer (score -1):

apply:

```
    background-image: url('');
```

to your css and it should work.

Comment: question is "how to change font color", not background. Or am I missing something?